# Is there a way to configure project paths outside of the solution file in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, csproj

I have a Visual Studio solution with the project I am working on (main project). The solution references a different project that main project requires as a dependency (dependency project).

The solution and the main project are located in one directory:

```
/mycode/main_project/main_project.sln
/mycode/main_project/main_project.csproj
```

The dependency project is located in a different directory:

```
/mycode/dependency_project/dependency_project.csproj
```

Both of these projects are under source control. I want to create some kind of configuration file for main project that is not under source control, so that another developer could clone both projects wherever they want and simply edit a non-source-controlled configuration file to allow the main project's solution to locate dependency project.

Currently, main solution locates dependency project using a relative path:

```
../dependency_project/dependency_project.csproj
```

If I enforce that all developers should clone these two projects to the same directory, the main solution will successfully link to the dependency project and everything will be happy. However, I would prefer that another developer *can* place the dependency project wherever they want.

Does Visual Studio 2019 Community support any kind of solution configuration file which could be kept ignored by version control and used to resolve the path to the dependency project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution files are very primitive and do not offer such a dynamic functionality.  However, if you don't need `dependency_project` to show up in the IDE, you can still reference it from `main_project.csproj` and that does give you more options.  It should still build fine even if the project doesn't show up in Solution Explorer.

For example, you could reference it through an environment variable, with a default expected path if that variable isn't set:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DependencyProjectPath Condition=" '$(DependencyProjectPath)' == ''>../dependency_project/dependency_project.csproj</DependencyProjectPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="$(DependencyProjectPath)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If you set the `DependencyProjectPath` environment variable before opening the solution (because VS inherits the environment variables from where it was launched), it will override the default setting here (based on the `Condition` attribute).

Comment: This is a good potential solution. However, one reason why I am linking it as a project reference is so that when debugging I can step directly into the code of dependency_project. When searching for bugs or issues, it is convenient to be able to step directly into the dependency's code to see if the issue is with the underlying library rather than the code using that library, or to double check the library's logic and verify if I am simply using it wrong.
Will I still be able to step into the code using the debugger? Or will this solution cause me to lose that functionality?

Comment: As far as debugging goes, as long as you load the symbols (or even use embedded symbols), the source metadata in the symbols should point to the source files where they exist on your machine.  Stepping into will work fine.  I often load symbols and step into code in repos completely unrelated to the one I'm working in.